# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

Trying to build a PDF using the [JS API PdfMake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
```

Then according to [this Helloworld](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted) , i run :

```
 var docDef={ content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake' }
 pdfMake.createPdf(docDef).download('optionalName.pdf');
```

i've got this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' of
> undefined

### Does **Roboto-Regular.ttf** File is required ?

### And Where to put it ,if so ?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved the problem importing pdfmake before vfs_fonts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

Comment: @bamse that means the **pdfmake** doesn't work without include `vfs_fonts.js` ?

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil it does not work without it. The default configuration requires pdfmake.min.js and vfs_fonts.js

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error with RequireJS. If you are using RequireJS you can solve it by specifying dependency in shim as follow:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'public/bower_components',
  waitSeconds: 200,
  paths: {
    'jquery' : 'jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    'bootstrap' : 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min',
    'pdfmake': '../js/pdfmake',
    'vfs_fonts':'../js/vfs_fonts' },
  shim: {
      bootstrap:{
          deps: ['jquery']
      },
      'vfs_fonts':{
         deps: ['pdfmake'] 
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but including the files using script tags, by the correct order, or with the require JS fix didn't work.

What worked for me was replacing vfs_fonts.js for its latest version from the pdfmake GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

I am working in Asp .Net MVC & had the same issue. I was including files in BundleConfig.cs. Then I moved files out from that file and placed those file directly in the view and it worked for me.